# I have an iPad app that plays audio in background but app icon is not appear with ipod controls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

My problem is - when audio is playing in background in my iPad then "my app icon" is not coming. I am using iPodMusicPlayer. For playing audio in background I have write these code..

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewDidAppear:animated];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
      [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
     [self resignFirstResponder];
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
        return YES;
}
```

// The iPod controls will send these events when the app is in the background

```
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {
       if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
           switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

           case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
               [self performSelector:@selector(playPause:)];
               break;

           case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            //[self previousSong:nil];
            //[self performSelector:@selector(previousSong:)];
            break;

           case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
               //[self performSelector:@selector(nextSong:)];
               break;
          default:
              break;
         }
     }
}
```

and info.plist I have also set "required background mode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also have to add `UIBackgroundModes` to your `Info.plist` and set its value to `audio`.

Please check the iOS App Programming Guide, specifically the [App States and Multitasking section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) for detailed info on how to execute tasks in background.

**[UPDATE]**

Also add these two lines to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your `AppDelegate.m`:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

And this code when you start playing your audio:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
[_player play];
newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
```

This should do it. Tested in the simulator, as well as on a device.

Comment: I have already set this value. I think problem is because of iPodMusicPlayer but not sure